# Ruby file storage not writing correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm writing a program which is *supposed* to store a theoretically infinite amount of numbers in Ruby, adding a new one each time the program is ran. It is supposed to ouput these numbers like so, say you ran it three times, entering 1, 2, and 3:

output line 1: #1: 1

output line 2: #2: 2

output line 3: #3: 3

The problem is, it doesn't do that. It just replaces what already exists in the file.

Here's the code:

```
def getNum
    print "Enter a number: "
    return gets.to_i
end

def writeFile
    if not File.file?("data.txt")
        data = File.new("data.txt", "w+")
        puts "[ File created? ]"
    else
        data = File.open("data.txt", "w+")
        puts "[ File opened. ]"
    end
    x = getNum
    File.write("data.txt", x, File.size?("data.txt"))
    data.close
    readFile
end

def readFile
    y = 0
    File.readlines("data.txt").each do |line|
        y += 1
        print y 
        print ": " + line
        puts

    end
end

writeFile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File.open(path, 'a')` will create the file if it doesn't exist and append to it.

So here's a simplified script to do that:

```
puts "enter num"
num = gets.chomp.to_i


File.open("data.txt", "a") { |f| f.write("#{num}\n") }

File.readlines("data.txt").each_with_index do |line, index|
  puts "output #{index + 1}: #{line}"
end
```

Example of running this:

```
max@max ~/Desktop> ruby script.rb 
enter num
1
output 1: 1
max@max ~/Desktop> ruby script.rb 
enter num
2
output 1: 1
output 2: 2
```

Note I added a `\n` to the `f.write` - this is so the appended text isn't all on the same line.

*alternatively, use `f.puts` which automatically includes the trailing newline* (thanks Amadan)

Comment: Why not simple `f.puts(num)`?

Comment: @Amadan I had a hunch that it existed, but didn't get around to trying it ... thanks